# how to store different response messages in different variable using botframework c#

Tags: c#, botframework

I want to store username and password from users response for ex. in chatbot..

```
user: Reset my password
BOt: Enter your username?? 
user: guest --> this response should be stored in username variable
Bot: Enter your password??
user: 12345 --> this response should be stored in pass variable
```

How to do this in c# code botframework

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your work so we can help you.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<11;i++)                                
{   if(activity.text.tolower.contains(reset my password) {                            
    await context.postssync($"Enter your Username??");                                      
    arr[i] = activity.text; } after this im not getting logic how to do

Comment: Please edit your question with your code and format it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are two alternatives:

1. You can add global variables in your dialog and store the values there
2. Use the BotBuilder's Data bags:

   - context.UserData
   - context.PrivateConversationData
   - context.ConversationData

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library which does this for you. In short the collected info is saved into Dialog options and in conversation data during turns assuming you are using personal (1-1) bots.

All these processing is done for you automatically and all you need to do is to declare what properties you need.

[Link to repo](https://github.com/sidecus/Zyin.IntentBot)